# How to sort the elements of an ArrayList<> alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, alphabetical-sort

I have created an `ArrayList` of FictionBooks and I'm trying to sort them alphabetically by the Author's name. Here's the code that I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Library implements Comparator<FictionBook> {
    private static final int CAPACITY = 200;
    public ArrayList<FictionBook> fictionBooks;

    public Library() {
        fictionBooks = new ArrayList<FictionBook>();
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public int compare(FictionBook o1, FictionBook o2) {
        if(o1.getAuthor() != null && o2.getAuthor() != null){
            return o1.getAuthor().compareTo(o2.getAuthor());
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(fictionBooks, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to use `Collections.sort` it gives me this error for sort:

> The method `sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` in the type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments `(ArrayList<FictionBook>, Comparator<String>)`
>   I will be grateful if you come up with a solution to my problem and share it with others.

Answer (score 0):

The `FictionBooks` Comparator is `Library`. This

```
 Collections.sort(fictionBooks, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

should be something like

```
 Collections.sort(fictionBooks, this);
```